# MenuPresenter can only be accessed from within the same library group prefix (referenced groupId=androidx.appcompat with prefix androidx from groupId

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appcompat, androidx

I'm currently updating the codebase for a project that I found on [Github](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/tree/a0f8fbc90d98eb1b629c6295dd2d3577412e7b1e) that uses a handy search feature.

I've updated most of the codebase however I keep getting issues similar to the post title, I have suppressed lint a number of times using the following code:

```
    //noinspection RestrictedApi
```

It seems to work at suppressing code inside my methods however there's a piece of code where I must implement a MenuPresenter interface which can be found in the following library:

```
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPresenter;
```

The implementation:

```
public class MenuPopupHelper implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnKeyListener,
    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener, PopupWindow.OnDismissListener,
     MenuPresenter {}
```

There doesn't seem to be any android documentation on androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPresenter. Any ideas on how I can work around this issue?

Comment: That's not a public class that any library should be implementing.